# Why does URL Hash is added instead of being replaced?

Tags: javascript, url, hash

When using a url like this:

```
http://localhost/nafham/?selection/12/24/122
```

The hashing is done in that manner:

```
http://localhost/nafham/?selection/12/24/122#?selection/12/24/122/الصف-الثالث-الثانوي/السنة-كاملة/الاقتصاد/self
```

However when any other part added to the URL, example:

```
http://localhost/nafham/?selection/12/24/122/test
```

The hash is added again on each action

```
http://localhost/nafham/?selection/12/24/122/test#?selection/12/24/122/الصف-الثالث-الثانوي/السنة-كاملة/الاقتصاد/self

http://localhost/nafham/?selection/12/24/122//test#?selection/12/24/122/test#?selection/12/24/93/الصف-الثالث-الثانوي/السنة-كاملة/الاقتصاد/self
```

Any idea why the Hash is added to the URL instead of replacing the current hash value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the part of the URL when you set the hash.

Comment: @MohamedSaid: That you need to make sure your hash is a hash, not an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.hash = "..."`. It should work.

Comment: Here's my code:
window.location.hash= '?selection/'+edu_year_selectionreal+'/'+semester_selectionreal+'/'+subject_selectionreal+'/'+edu_year_selectiontitle+'/'+semester_selectiontitle+'/'+subject_selectiontitle+'/self';

Comment: @MohamedSaid Exactly. That's wrong. The hash shouldn't have a URL in it. Perhaps you meant window.query = .....